# creating string of characters from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to print a string from a dictionary in python.

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{'A': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'G'], 'C': ['C', 'A', 'G'], 'T': ['T', 'C'], 'G': ['T', 'A']}
```

I want to extract a string from above dictionary.

I need to start from character 'G' and print it then print the first character in value list of G which is 'T'. Then delete this character and go to key 'T' and print first character in 'T' value list and remove it and continue this process until all values are removed.

out put must looks like:

```
GTTCCAACGAAG
```

how can I get this out put by iterating through the dictionary in python

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Show us your best attempt and the output you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should solve your issue:

```
data = {'A': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'G'], 'C': ['C', 'A', 'G'], 'T': ['T', 'C'], 'G': ['T', 'A']}

start = 'G'
result = [start]

reached_end = False

while not reached_end:
    if data[start]:
        value = data[start].pop(0)
        result.append(value)
        start = value
    else:
        reached_end = True

print(''.join(result))
```

Prints:
`GTTCCAACGAAG`